# RODBC query brings down Shiny Server

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc, shiny

We are running a Shiny Server (and Shiny Dashboard) on RedHat 6.7 and have been running into a segfault when trying to query a database using RODBC. This happens when we source the file into app.R or make a query request to the database in the server.R file. When we run the same code in the R console it works just fine.

It seems like there must be some type of interaction between Shiny and RODBC that is causing this issue. As a workaround we are using the RJDBC, which works fine, but we're worried it isn't going to scale well for us. And it's quite slow.

Anyone have an idea what we can do to make RODBC work correctly?

**Here is the code we are running to generate the error:**

```
library(RODBC)
myConn <- odbcConnect("DSN_Name")
segment <- sqlQuery(myConn, "SELECT * FROM foo")
```

If you use a basic Shiny app and add the code from above you'll be able to re-create the error. Here is code from [RStudio](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson1/).

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(
# Application title
titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
# Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("bins",
              "Number of bins:",
              min = 1,
              max = 50,
              value = 30)
),

# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("distPlot")
)
  )
    ))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
# Expression that generates a histogram. The expression is
# wrapped in a call to renderPlot to indicate that:
#
#  1) It is "reactive" and therefore should re-execute automatically
#     when inputs change
#  2) Its output type is a plot
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
x    <- faithful[, 2]  # Old Faithful Geyser data
bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

# draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
})
  })
```

**Here is the error message from the server:**

```
An error has occurred

The application exited unexpectedly.

socket hang up

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:37079 Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’: box

Loading required package: ggplot2

Attaching package: ‘plotly’ The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’: last_plot

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’: layout Attaching package: ‘DT’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:shiny’: dataTableOutput, renderDataTable

Loading required package: DBI Loading required package: rJava Loading required package:

NLP Attaching package: ‘NLP’ The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’: annotate

Loading required package: RColorBrewer

*** caught segfault ***
address (nil), cause 'unknown'

Traceback:
1: .Call(C_RODBCDriverConnect, as.character(connection), id, as.integer(believeNRows), as.logical(readOnlyOptimize))
2: odbcDriverConnect("DSN=DB_Name")
3: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
4: eval(expr, p)
5: eval.parent(Call)
6: odbcConnect("DB_Name")
7: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
8: eval(ei, envir)
9: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
10: source("RODBC.R")
11: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
12: eval(ei, envir)
13: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
14: source(file, ..., keep.source = TRUE, encoding = checkEncoding(file))
15: sourceUTF8(fullpath, local = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
16: func(fname, ...)
17: appObj()
18: handler(req)
19: handler(req)
20: handler(...)
21: handlers$invoke(req)
22: handler(req)
23: func(req)
24: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
25: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
26: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
27: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) { call <- conditionCall(e) if (!is.null(call)) { if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch))) call <- sys.call(-4L) dcall <- deparse(call)[1L] prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ") LONG <- 75L msg <- conditionMessage(e) sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]] w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w") if (is.na(w)) w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "b") if (w > LONG) prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n ") } else prefix <- "Error : " msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n") .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L])) if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"), TRUE)) { cat(msg, file = stderr()) .Internal(printDeferredWarnings()) } invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
28: try({ inputStream <- if (is.null(data)) nullInputStream else InputStream$new(data, dataLength) req$rook.input <- inputStream req$rook.errors <- ErrorStream$new() req$httpuv.version <- packageVersion("httpuv") if (!is.null(req$HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE)) req$CONTENT_TYPE <- req$HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE if (!is.null(req$HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH)) req$CONTENT_LENGTH <- req$HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH resp <- func(req) if (is.null(resp) || length(resp) == 0) return(NULL) resp$headers <- lapply(resp$headers, paste) if ("file" %in% names(resp$body)) { filename <- resp$body[["file"]] owned <- FALSE if ("owned" %in% names(resp$body)) owned <- as.logical(resp$body$owned) resp$body <- NULL resp$bodyFile <- filename resp$bodyFileOwned <- owned } resp})
29: rookCall(.app$call, req, req$.bodyData, seek(req$.bodyData))
30: (function (req) { on.exit({ if (!is.null(req$.bodyData)) { close(req$.bodyData) } req$.bodyData <- NULL }) rookCall(.app$call, req, req$.bodyData, seek(req$.bodyData))})(<environment>)
31: eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos)
32: evalq((function (req) { on.exit({ if (!is.null(req$.bodyData)) { close(req$.bodyData) } req$.bodyData <- NULL }) rookCall(.app$call, req, req$.bodyData, seek(req$.bodyData))})(<environment>), <environment>)
33: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
34: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
35: tryCatchList(expr, names[-nh], parentenv, handlers[-nh])
36: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
37: tryCatchOne(tryCatchList(expr, names[-nh], parentenv, handlers[-nh]), names[nh], parentenv, handlers[[nh]])
38: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
39: tryCatch(evalq((function (req) { on.exit({ if (!is.null(req$.bodyData)) { close(req$.bodyData) } req$.bodyData <- NULL }) rookCall(.app$call, req, req$.bodyData, seek(req$.bodyData))})(<environment>), <environment>), error = function (x) x, interrupt = function (x) x)
40: .Call("httpuv_run", PACKAGE = "httpuv", timeoutMillis)
41: run(timeoutMs)
42: service(timeout)
43: serviceApp()
44: withCallingHandlers(expr, error = function(e) { handle <- getOption("shiny.error") if (is.function(handle)) handle()})
45: shinyCallingHandlers(while (!.globals$stopped) { serviceApp() Sys.sleep(0.001)})
46: runApp(Sys.getenv("SHINY_APP"), port = port, launch.browser = FALSE) aborting ...
```

Comment: Can you format that error in plain text so it is readable?

Comment: I reformatted the error so that it's more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to thank Joe Cheng at RStudio. He was a massive help and really went out of his way to help me resolve this issue. Thanks a ton.

So the issue that I ran into was the result of (IMHO) poor code structure. Here were the mistakes I made and once they were fixed things worked as expected.

- Mistake 1 - I was calling the server.R file app.R. This is an
  outdated naming convention and shouldn't be used.
- Mistake 2 - The
  last line of my server.R file called the function shinyApp(ui,
  server). This was causing major issues with my odbc driver to my
  database. It was creating a very large stack where my client would be
  pushed too far down and result in a seg fault. Moral of the story,
  end your server.R file with the server function.

My shiny server is now happily running! : )

Thanks to Joe for all the help.

Here is the complete thread - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/66Ve60ugmHs

Comment: Do you mean: 1.  Split `app.R` to `server.R` and `ui.R`? 2. Close DB connection to  solve the issue? Thanks.